# Issues with counting the number of list items

Tags: javascript

I have a dilemma. Basically I am trying to get the length a list of cards and do some assertion to validate the number of cards is equal to 2. For some reason I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).getElementsByTagName is not a function
```

This is what the code looks like:

```
<ul class="UserPaymentsContent__cardList" style="">
<li class="UserPaymentsContent__cardList__item" >
</li>
<li class="UserPaymentsContent__cardList__item" >
</li>
</ul>
```

And here is the code that I ran:

```
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("UserPaymentsContent__cardList UserPaymentsContent__cardList__item").getElementsByTagName("li").length)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> document.getElementsByClassName("UserPaymentsContent__cardList")[0].children.length

This should work for your purpose. *document.getElementsByClassName("UserPaymentsContent__cardList")* gives you array of HTMLCollection objects. First element is your *ul* parent object which you are looking for.

Comment: amazing, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll`

```js
const lis = document.querySelectorAll('.UserPaymentsContent__cardList__item');

console.log(lis.length);
```

```html
<ul class="UserPaymentsContent__cardList" style="">
  <li class="UserPaymentsContent__cardList__item" >
  </li>
  <li class="UserPaymentsContent__cardList__item" >
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error tells you, that no elements have been found by the class query.

The problem seems to be that you are searching for an element with one class OR the other. The getElementByClass operation only searches for elements having ALL the classes.